# python: Binance error of using get_account()

Tags: python, websocket, algorithmic-trading, binance

A few days ago this was working fine uploading data but today its giving the error of:
bal = info['balances']
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable.
and
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientBase._request' was never awaited

```
info = client.get_account()
print("ACCOUNT BALANCE INFO")
bal = info['balances']
print("BALANCE:")
for b in bal:
    if float(b['free']) > 0:
        print(b)
```

Comment: Still dont know the exact problem but somehow fixed it with asyncio:

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my pc was not sync. Easy fix (windows):
search date and time settings -> synchronise your clock -> Sync now